# jquery anchor offset using previous/next tags

Tags: jquery, offset

We are using jquery attached to a ul menu list to scroll to anchors in the website. The website is horizontal. At the moment, it is all working fine via the hook a href of #pane01, #pane02, #pane03 etc. (each div id is given this)

Code is:

```
$('ul.submenu a').bind('click',function(event){
var $anchor = $(this);
$('html, body').stop().animate({
scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left - 200
}, 1000);
event.preventDefault();
});
```

What we want to do, is use a floating previous/next link to scroll back and forth between these panels. So, if they are on #pane03 clicking previous would go to #pane02 and next would go to #pane04.

How can I do that via jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Since your scrolling is already working fine for you. You just need to set an active class on your `<a>` once it's clicked. This will serve as your selector for your previous and next link.

I suppose this is a similar markup:

```
<div>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#pane01" class="active">Panel 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pane01">Panel 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pane01">Panel 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a id="prev">Previous</a>
<a id="next">Next</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul.submenu a').bind('click',function(event){
    var $anchor = $(this);
    //setting active on <a>
    $anchor.addClass('active').parent('li').siblings().children('a').removeClass('active');

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left - 200
    }, 1000);
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    $('ul.submenu a.active').parent('li').prev().children('a').trigger('click');
});

$('#next').click(function(){
    $('ul.submenu a.active').parent('li').next().children('a').trigger('click');
});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/4fdm5/1/)